# Is there a name for the command line user interface employed by projects like Git?

Tags: command-line, bash, git

There are quite a few command line tools (or suites of tools) out there these days which use a command line interface such that every command starts with the name of the application/tool followed by a space and one of several available "subcommands". Git, for instance, has many different subcommands: "git status", "git init", "git fetch", "git commit", etc.

Just a few other projects I can think of which also use this pattern are:

- vagrant ("vagrant up", "vagrant destroy", "vagrant status")
- go(lang) ("go run", "go vet", "go fmt", "go build")
- svn ("svn checkout", "svn update", "svn commit")
- crosstool-ng ("ct-ng help", "ct-ng build", "ct-ng menuconfig")
- repo ("repo sync", "repo help", "repo init")

And this is far from a comprehensive list.

Some examples of command-line applications which do not use this pattern (but could if designed slightly differently):

- pacman (Arch Linux's package manager. Uses flag-style "subcommands" in contrast to the pattern about which I'm asking. "pacman -Q", "pacman -S", "pacman -R", etc)
- portage/"emerge" (Gentoo's package manager)
- ImageMagick (rather than separate subcommands, it uses separate *commands*. "convert", "import", "animate", "compare", "composite", etc)

My question is "is there a name specifically for this 'subcommand' style of command-line interface pattern and if so what is it?"

Comment: It's not a new pattern (pointing at "these days").  Consider `cvs`.

Comment: Yeah. That's true. Is it fair to say its proliferation is fairly new, however? (I honestly don't know.)

Comment: `-r` is a command line switch .. just as `/r` is or just plain `subcommand`.. you're confused on what a [`command line interface`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) is. There aren't any "patterns" to command line switches, it's whatever the implementer of the software wants to do.

Comment: I'm not confused, but apparently I'm not communicating very well. Also, there are indeed patterns and styles to command line interfaces just as there are patterns/styles to code ("design patterns"), gui interfaces ("look and feel"), and for that matter musical, literary, and artistic styles. They're all reflections of the author's/composer's/programmer's own preferences, inclinations, and influences.

Comment: Finally, I'd say the leading dash (perhaps subtly) implies a different kind of usage than the full-word no-leading-dash command line arguments do. Not from a *technical* perspective, but rather from a semantic one.

Comment: Just as a checkbox in a gui indicates that multiple may be simultaneously selected while a radio button indicates that only one may be selected at a time. There are exceptions to the rules subcommands and/or swithes imply just as there are cases where multiple of what appear to be radio buttons can sometimes be selected simultaneously and some applications use what look like checkboxes even when only one may be selected at a time.

Answer (score 1):

In *The Go Programming Language* by Brian W. Kernighan and Alan A. A. Donovan, the `go` tool is described as it «uses the **‹Swiss army knife› style**, with over a dozen subcommands» (p. 290).